# Mssql select returning error for some queries

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

```
Array
(
    [0] => 01S02
    [1] => 0
    [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Cursor type changed (SQLExecute[0] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:250)
    [3] => 01S02
)
```

This is the error I am getting when I do select in my mssql database. I only get this on some query and I dont get it in some query. I am using the same select.

I want to know why I am getting this kind of error in my mssql select.

Some times I get

```
Array
(
    [0] => 42000
    [1] => 8114
    [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Error converting data type varchar to numeric. (SQLExecute[8114] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:254)
    [3] => 42000
)
```

> What does these error means?

Comment: Not sure about the first error, but the second error looks like you have some bad SQL Server code which is messing around with types.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen any idea on what causes `Cursor type changed` is the data types as well? on something elese?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20436426/cursor-type-changed-error-on-perl-ole32-mssql-dateadd-function-results) for a possible answer.  It could just be related to the second error of mixing up types.  I'd focus on finding and fixing the second error, and maybe the first one will go away too.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry to ask again i also happened to get this error `Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 0
    [2] =>  ((null)[0] at (null):0)
    [3] => 
)
` what could cause  this

Comment: Hi Martin, you're going to need to closely examine the actual SQL you are running.  Note that the errors don't necessarily have anything to do with PHP, other than that perhaps your code is what is calling the underlying queries.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes i have.. there are just certain record when being searched will return these error.. what i do is select directly in mssql then do the same search with a column in the project and im getting these. Im still trying to debugg as i post this comment im trying to get the root of the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150528/discussion-between-martin-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen tim a little help with `Ñ` i think this is the reason how can i return this in php. what i have in is `$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                print_r($result);
                echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);` please disregard the `print_r` echo does not show anything when i think there is the  `Ñ` char

Answer (score 0):

Because in your code can't convert `varchar to numeric`

Comment: This should be a comment.  If you can't comment, and don't have enough material for a complete answer, then just sit back and watch the show.